# CSS Grid does not display

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Starting to practice CSS grid for the 1st time but it does not display at all in Chrome. 
When I launch the .html, only the margins are displayed but every other element are displayed as a block like :

panenka

accueil

maillots

survêtements

coques

```css
img img

.logo {
    grid-area: logo
  }
  
  .nav {
    grid-area: nav
  }
  
  .little {
    grid-area: little
  }
  
  .container {
    margin: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "logo . . . . ."
    "nav nav . . . little";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="edit3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <body class="container">
        <header> 
            <div class="logo">
                <h1> Panenka </h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <h3> Accueil </h3>
                <h3> Maillots </h3>
                <h3> Survêtements </h3>
                <h3> Coques </h3>
            </nav>
        
            <div class="little">
                <img src= "" alt = "rechercher">
                <img src ="" alt = "panier">
            </div>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have idea to help me out, would be nice ! Thanks you )

Comment: missing `;` at the end of template-columns

Comment: @TemaniAfif the ; issue has been fixed but no changes on the display

Comment: you are apply grid to the body so only he header is a grid element, move it to the header

Answer (score 0):

`container` should be on the direct parent which is `header` not `body`

```css
.logo {
    grid-area: logo
  }
  
  .nav {
    grid-area: nav
  }
  
  .little {
    grid-area: little
  }
  
  .container {
    margin: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "logo . . . . ."
    "nav nav . . . little";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="edit3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <body>
        <header  class="container"> 
            <div class="logo">
                <h1> Panenka </h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <h3> Accueil </h3>
                <h3> Maillots </h3>
                <h3> Survêtements </h3>
                <h3> Coques </h3>
            </nav>
        
            <div class="little">
                <img src= "" alt = "rechercher">
                <img src ="" alt = "panier">
            </div>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```